# Python - Unable to read xlsx sheet using XLRD module

Tags: python, xlsx, xlrd

I'm trying to read an xlsx sheet and append it to a LIST. But, the below code throws an error. I'm unable to decrypt what the error is.
Can someone help pls?

Error:
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

My Code:

```
import xlrd
df = []
with xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\Tad\Documents\test.xlsx') as wb:
        with wb.get_sheet('Selected products') as sheet:
            for row in sheet.rows():
                df.append([item.v for item in row])
```

Also if I use "`with wb.sheet_by_name('Selected products') as sheet:`", The error is: "`AttributeError: __enter__`"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use xlrd for new excel files.  Instead use openpyxl.

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```